# Implementing insert operation using knex.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am trying to insert data into "teacher" table when a server received a request. The problem that I have is when we insert the data it needs to return only the newly added rows, but my code is showing all the content in the "teacher" table. I am new to full-stack web development and if you can help me with this it will be a huge help

The addTeacher function is as below

```
const addTeacher = async (id, name, age) => {
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO teacher(id,name,age) values (?, ?, ?)'
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        knex_db
            .raw(sql)
            .then((data) => {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, @JMB! Thank you for using StackOverflow to improve your skills. It doesn't look like this question was not answered before. The answer to this question is even in the official knex documentation.
I know that this is not the answer you were hoping for. To make everyone's life better at SO, please check this Meta Question to better understand what is the best time to ask questions here. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1162326
Thank you